# maximum Height for dialog themed activity

Tags: android, layout, android-windowmanager

I have a Dialog themed activity containing a list view and i want to set a maximum height equals half the screen, if I set only the height the activity takes half the screen size always even if it has one element. What I want is setting a maximum height for the activity.

here's my code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.width = (int) (MyApplication.screenWidth * 0.95);
    lp.height = (int) (MyApplication.screenHeight * 0.5);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    this.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```